# Problem with matrix dots

Tags: errors

Why do I have the following problem? I've tried \cdots[image].

Comment: Please, post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)...

Comment: @Jossie Your actual problem isn't clear though; for all we know, you could have wanted vertical dots, dots that slanted, any number of things. Next time, you really need to be specific about the problem you're having.

Comment: Sorry @Sean. I'll keep that in mind; I however wonder if that is a red herring in regards to this problem...:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is you haven't defined all the columns you want in the `tabular` environment. `\begin{tabular}{ccc}` only defines a table with 3 columns; add another `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays

Has everything you need about dots and such.